# RC522 and MIFARE Plus

Tags: arduino, mifare

I'm new to MIFARE and I got a RC522 to read some cards. With [this](https://github.com/miguelbalboa/rfid) library I could read some CLASSICS 1K, 4K and ULTRALIGHT cards/tags. But when I try to read some MIFARE PLUS, nothing happens.

I'm still studying MIFARE standards to improve my knowledge, but I'm pretty lost here. Since the RC522 could read the MIFARE family, why couldn't it read a PLUS? Even the UID? I understand that to read an UID you don't need to authenticate, right?

I tried to debug the SAK response from RC522 library, but do not get any response by PLUS cards.

So, what I'm missing here? Can someone give a guide to my work?

- I'm using Arduino.

Thanks!

BR from Brazil.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. MIFARE PLUS cards are encrypted with AES 128, if i'm not wrong you need a SAM AV2 module from NXP.

I also tryed to read a MIFARE PLUS Card with a smartphone, and it throws randoms UIDs. That happend because I don't have de key to decrypt it.

Comment: Yes, it make sense! I already read something about it. We have a MC531 here too, that reads PLUS cards with or without SAM. I'm looking for a cheaper module (RC522). So, I will try to figure out how it works and post here. Thanks for your attention Javier.

Answer (score -1):

I tried to read mifare plus x by module rc522. You need to change inductance l1 l2 follow topic:
https://forum.mikroe.com/viewtopic.php?f=147&t=64203
 You can read UID, SAK, ... but if you want read/write data. You need to authenticate AES 128, it's seem difficult to me.